# Perl: Reset $1 variable

Tags: perl

I have a subroutine that works on the first time it is called but on the second time, if the URL is not valid, it uses the previous value of `$1`. Is there a simple way to rest the value of `$1` or to be equal to a NULL value?

Edit: Here is my code

```
our %hash;
sub GetOnce{
    $mech->get($_[0]);
    $val = $mech->content;
    $val =~ /value="(.*?)"/;
    if($1 ne "") {$hash{$_[1]} = $1;}
}
GetNonce("http://URL1", "VAR1"); #Valid URL
GetNonce("http://URL2", "VAR2"); #Timesout
```

I just want to reset the value for Error Handling. I.e. if URL1 is valid but URL2 is invalid or timesout, then `$1` will be the same for both of them. If URL1 is invalid/timesout and URL2 is valid, then only the $1 from URL2 is saved. And if they're both valid, then the program stores each of their $1's.

Comment: Aren't you testing if your match is successful or not?

Comment: Post a little sample code, please.  In general you should only be accessing $1 if you have a positive pattern match result.

Comment: Typically you do something like this: `print $1 if m/foo (bar)/;` (replace `print` with whatever you're doing to manipulate `$1`)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: That did not work, i used `$hash{$_[1]} = $1 if $val =~ /giveaways_nonce" value="(.*?)"/;` and it outputted same thing

Comment: @Bijan I assume you're using `WWW::Mechanize`? If so, are you using `autocheck => 1` (the default)? This will `croak` on error, so you shouldn't even get to the regex for the failed request. Regardless, the assignment in `$hash{$_[1]} = $1 if $val =~ /giveaways_nonce" value="(.*?)"/;` will only run if the match succeeds; double check the contents of `$val`. In your snippet, `$val` appears to be a global, or at least a lexical variable that you're not passing as a parameter; I wouldn't be surprised if it was being changed elsewhere in your code.

Comment: I am using `WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS`. The problem was that on an invalid url, $mech->content was not updating which would leave `$val` as the old value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest not using `$1`, and instead:

```
my ( $match ) = ( $val =~ m/value="(.*?)"/ );
```

Useful feature of pattern matching like this - in a scalar context, it's a 'true/false' but in a list context, it returns a list of matches. Which you can then assign to individual scalars.

So anyway - `$match` is `undef` if the match fails, and whatever is in the match if it worked. You should make a point of using `defined` to test this though, because if the value in `$match` is `0` or `''` it'll *evaluate* false, despite having worked.

E.g.:

```
our %hash;
sub GetOnce{
    my ( $url, $key ) = @_; 
    $mech->get($url);
    my ( $match ) = ( $mech -> content =~ m/value="(.*?)"/ ); 
    #may not need to test it -  you could just have an undef value. 
    if ( defined $match ) { $hash{$key} = $match };
}
```

Comment: Your code is providing the same output but I found out why.. I moved declaration of `$mech` to beginning of subroutine

Answer (score 3):

You should test the regex match itself, rather than the value of the captures. It is also best to *name* the values in `@_`, and to use a complementary character class instead of a non-greedy match in your regex.

Like this

```
our %hash;

sub get_once {
    my ($url, $key) = @_;
    $mech->get($url);
    my $content = $mech->content;
    $hash{$key} = $1 if $content =~ /value="([^"]*)"/;
}
```